# Python - Update (edit) form not showing

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have been reading the django documentation, googling for days where none have the same problem as me. It seems that method "member_edit" in "Views.py" does not return any data and therefor can not show me the form.

Hopefully, some of you can spot where I went wrong. Appreciate all the help I can get!

Models.py

```
class Member(models.Model):
   member_no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
   email = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
   reg_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

   class Meta:
       db_table = 'Member'
```

Forms.py

```
class RegForm(forms.ModelForm):
   first_name = forms.CharField(
       widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
       max_length=30,
       required=True)
   last_name = forms.CharField(
       widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
       max_length=30,
       required=True)
   email = forms.CharField(
       widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
       required=True,
       max_length=75)
   reg_date = forms.DateField(widget=DateWidget(usel10n=True,bootstrap_version=3))

   class Meta:
       model = Member
       exclude = ['last_login', 'date_joined']
       fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'reg_date', ]
```

Views.py

```
def member_edit(request, member_no):
   member = Member.objects.get(member_no=member_no)
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = RegForm(request.POST or None, instance=member)
      if form.is_valid():
         member.first_name = form.request.POST['first_name']
         member.last_name = form.request.POST['last_name']
         member.email = form.request.POST['email']
         member.reg_date = form.request.POST['reg_date']
         member.save()
         return redirect('member_overview')
   return render(request, 'member/member_signup.html')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^member_edit/(?P<member_no>\d+)$', views.member_edit, name='member_edit')
]
```

member_edit.html

```
{% block body %}
<h1 class="logo"><a href="{% url 'member_overview' %}">Members</a></h1>
<div class="signup">
 <h2>{% trans 'Update member' %}</h2>
   <form action="{% url 'member_edit' member.member_no %}"  method="post" role="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
      {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
          <label for="{{ field.label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              {{ field }}
              {% if field.help_text %}
                <span class="help-block">{{ field.help_text }}</span>
              {% endif %}
              {% for error in field.errors %}
                <label class="control-label">{{ error }}</label>
              {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
  <center>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{% trans 'Update member' %}</button>
   </center>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing the form in the context (and the template name appears to be incorrect?):

```
def member_edit(request, member_no):
   member = Member.objects.get(member_no=member_no)
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = RegForm(request.POST or None, instance=member)
      if form.is_valid():
         # This isn't necessary - just save the form
         #member.first_name = form.request.POST['first_name']
         #member.last_name = form.request.POST['last_name']
         #member.email = form.request.POST['email']
         #member.reg_date = form.request.POST['reg_date']
         #member.save()
         form.save()
         return redirect('member_overview')
   # Instantiate the form
   form = RegForm(instance=member)
   # Add a dictionary for the context
   return render(request, 'member/member_edit.html', {'form': form, 'member': member)
```

You could make this cleaner (and easier) though with [a generic class based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView):

```
from django.views import generic
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class UpdateMember(generic.UpdateView):
     model = Member
     form_class = RegForm
     pk_url_kwarg = 'member_no'
     template_name = 'member/member_edit.html'
     success_url = reverse_lazy('member_overview')
```

Think I got all the attributes you need there - you can check out [CCBV](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.10/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/) it's a great resource for the class based views.

Take a look at the documentation on [views and templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial03/)

Comment: Changed the templates name it gives me this error:

**Reverse for 'member_edit' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['member_edit/(?P<member_no>\\d+)$']**

Comment: Forgot you were also referencing member in the template - you have to pass that into the context as well. Updated my answer.

Comment: Ohhh, almost there =O
Now the form is empty, i was expecting data to be shown so i could edit it xD 

https://gyazo.com/c9e64057781744c4bf3878ab42eb829f

Labels are bit weird..expect it to be on the left not on the right xD

Comment: Ah, in that case, you need to add `instance` to the form - updated my answer. Also added another option for you to use that might make things easier.

Comment: They are showing =D buuuuut...when i try to update information added..nothing happens xD it won't redirect me to "member_overview" xD

Comment: found another way to implement it..so thx for all the help!! =D